# how can we add mousewheel with Multiple Owl Carousel?

Tags: jquery, owl-carousel

My project involves creating a team and Blog etc.. with `Owl Carousel`. I'm using `Owl Carousel`.

i am using Two time `Owl Carousel` in One page so i am trying to move with `mousewheel` but it worked with last Owl Slider but not others.!

**HTML**

```
<div class="v2-team-section">
<div class="container">
<div id="v2-team-carousel" class="team-main owl-carousel">
  <div class="team">
    <div class="team-image" style="background-image: url(images/works-1.jpg);"></div>
    <div class="team-detail">
      <div class="team-name">Jhon Smith</div>
      <div class="team-category">Photographer + Cat Lover</div>
      <div class="team-social">
        <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></a>
        <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a>
        <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-dribbble"></i></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="team">
    <div class="team-image" style="background-image: url(images/works-1.jpg);"></div>
    <div class="team-detail">
      <div class="team-name">Jhon Smith</div>
      <div class="team-category">Photographer + Cat Lover</div>
      <div class="team-social">
        <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></a>
        <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a>
        <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-dribbble"></i></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="team">
    <div class="team-image" style="background-image: url(images/works-1.jpg);"></div>
    <div class="team-detail">
      <div class="team-name">Jhon Smith</div>
      <div class="team-category">Photographer + Cat Lover</div>
      <div class="team-social">
        <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></a>
        <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a>
        <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-dribbble"></i></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="team">
    <div class="team-image" style="background-image: url(images/works-1.jpg);"></div>
    <div class="team-detail">
      <div class="team-name">Jhon Smith</div>
      <div class="team-category">Photographer + Cat Lover</div>
      <div class="team-social">
        <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></a>
        <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a>
        <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-dribbble"></i></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="team">
    <div class="team-image" style="background-image: url(images/works-1.jpg);"></div>
    <div class="team-detail">
      <div class="team-name">Jhon Smith</div>
      <div class="team-category">Photographer + Cat Lover</div>
      <div class="team-social">
        <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></a>
        <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a>
        <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-dribbble"></i></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 </div>
  </div>


<div class="v2-blog-section">
<div class="container">
<div id="v2-blog-carousel" class="home-blog-main owl-carousel">
  <div class="blog-col">
    <div class="blog-image" style="background-image: url(images/works-1.jpg);"></div>
    <div class="blog-detail">
      <a href="#" class="blog-title">The Role design plays in our daily life</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="blog-col">
    <div class="blog-image" style="background-image: url(images/works-1.jpg);"></div>
    <div class="blog-detail">
      <a href="#" class="blog-title">The Role design plays in our daily life</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="blog-col">
    <div class="blog-image" style="background-image: url(images/works-1.jpg);"></div>
    <div class="blog-detail">
      <a href="#" class="blog-title">The Role design plays in our daily life</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="blog-col">
    <div class="blog-image" style="background-image: url(images/works-1.jpg);"></div>
    <div class="blog-detail">
      <a href="#" class="blog-title">The Role design plays in our daily life</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="blog-col">
    <div class="blog-image" style="background-image: url(images/works-1.jpg);"></div>
    <div class="blog-detail">
      <a href="#" class="blog-title">The Role design plays in our daily life</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="blog-col">
    <div class="blog-image" style="background-image: url(images/works-1.jpg);"></div>
    <div class="blog-detail">
      <a href="#" class="blog-title">The Role design plays in our daily life</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 </div>
```

**jQuery**

```
  /* V2 Team Carousel */
 if(document.querySelector('#v2-team-carousel')){
 var owl = $('#v2-team-carousel');
 owl.owlCarousel({
    navText: ["<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='31.135' height='18.057' viewBox='0 0 31.135 18.057'><g id='Group_411' data-name='Group 411' transform='translate(-3 -9.623)'><path id='Path_3205' data-name='Path 3205' d='M31.832,10.479a1.211,1.211,0,0,0-1.714,0l-7.264,7.264a1.211,1.211,0,0,0,0,1.714l7.264,7.264a1.212,1.212,0,0,0,1.714-1.714L25.423,18.6l6.41-6.408a1.211,1.211,0,0,0,0-1.714Z' transform='translate(-18.997)' fill='#fff' stroke='#fff' stroke-width='1' fill-rule='evenodd'/><path id='Path_3206' data-name='Path 3206' d='M32.422,18.086a1.211,1.211,0,0,0-1.211-1.211H4.711a1.211,1.211,0,0,0,0,2.421h26.5A1.211,1.211,0,0,0,32.422,18.086Z' transform='translate(1.213 0.514)' fill='#fff' stroke='#fff' stroke-width='1' fill-rule='evenodd'/></g></svg>","<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='31.135' height='18.057' viewBox='0 0 31.135 18.057'><g id='Group_412' data-name='Group 412' transform='translate(-3 -9.623)'><path id='Path_3205' data-name='Path 3205' d='M22.854,10.479a1.211,1.211,0,0,1,1.714,0l7.264,7.264a1.211,1.211,0,0,1,0,1.714l-7.264,7.264a1.212,1.212,0,0,1-1.714-1.714L29.263,18.6l-6.41-6.408a1.211,1.211,0,0,1,0-1.714Z' transform='translate(1.447)' fill='#fff' stroke='#fff' stroke-width='1' fill-rule='evenodd'/><path id='Path_3206' data-name='Path 3206' d='M3.5,18.086a1.211,1.211,0,0,1,1.211-1.211h26.5a1.211,1.211,0,1,1,0,2.421H4.711A1.211,1.211,0,0,1,3.5,18.086Z' transform='translate(0 0.514)' fill='#fff' stroke='#fff' stroke-width='1' fill-rule='evenodd'/></g></svg>"],
    margin: 20,
    nav: false,
    dots: false,
    loop: true,
    smartSpeed: 1000,
    responsive: {
        0: {
            items: 1
        },
        576: {
            items: 2
        },
        768: {
            items: 3
        },
        1200: {
            items: 4
        }
    }
});
owl.on('mousewheel', '.owl-stage', function (e) {
    if (e.deltaY>0) {
        owl.trigger('prev.owl');
    } else {
        owl.trigger('next.owl');
    }
    e.preventDefault();
});
}
/* V2 Blog Carousel */
if(document.querySelector('#v2-blog-carousel')){
var owl = $('#v2-blog-carousel');
owl.owlCarousel({
    navText: ["<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='31.135' height='18.057' viewBox='0 0 31.135 18.057'><g id='Group_411' data-name='Group 411' transform='translate(-3 -9.623)'><path id='Path_3205' data-name='Path 3205' d='M31.832,10.479a1.211,1.211,0,0,0-1.714,0l-7.264,7.264a1.211,1.211,0,0,0,0,1.714l7.264,7.264a1.212,1.212,0,0,0,1.714-1.714L25.423,18.6l6.41-6.408a1.211,1.211,0,0,0,0-1.714Z' transform='translate(-18.997)' fill='#fff' stroke='#fff' stroke-width='1' fill-rule='evenodd'/><path id='Path_3206' data-name='Path 3206' d='M32.422,18.086a1.211,1.211,0,0,0-1.211-1.211H4.711a1.211,1.211,0,0,0,0,2.421h26.5A1.211,1.211,0,0,0,32.422,18.086Z' transform='translate(1.213 0.514)' fill='#fff' stroke='#fff' stroke-width='1' fill-rule='evenodd'/></g></svg>","<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='31.135' height='18.057' viewBox='0 0 31.135 18.057'><g id='Group_412' data-name='Group 412' transform='translate(-3 -9.623)'><path id='Path_3205' data-name='Path 3205' d='M22.854,10.479a1.211,1.211,0,0,1,1.714,0l7.264,7.264a1.211,1.211,0,0,1,0,1.714l-7.264,7.264a1.212,1.212,0,0,1-1.714-1.714L29.263,18.6l-6.41-6.408a1.211,1.211,0,0,1,0-1.714Z' transform='translate(1.447)' fill='#fff' stroke='#fff' stroke-width='1' fill-rule='evenodd'/><path id='Path_3206' data-name='Path 3206' d='M3.5,18.086a1.211,1.211,0,0,1,1.211-1.211h26.5a1.211,1.211,0,1,1,0,2.421H4.711A1.211,1.211,0,0,1,3.5,18.086Z' transform='translate(0 0.514)' fill='#fff' stroke='#fff' stroke-width='1' fill-rule='evenodd'/></g></svg>"],
    margin: 20,
    nav: false,
    dots: false,
    loop: true,
    smartSpeed: 1000,
    responsive: {
        0: {
            items: 1
        },
        576: {
            items: 1
        },
        768: {
            items: 2
        },
        1200: {
            items: 3
        }
    }
});
owl.on('mousewheel', '.owl-stage', function (e) {
    if (e.deltaY>0) {
        owl.trigger('prev.owl');
    } else {
        owl.trigger('next.owl');
    }
    e.preventDefault();
});
}
```

here is [Pen](https://codepen.io/scalescript/pen/ZELpbgM)

Comment: I imagine this is probably due to the reuse/double declaration of the `owl` variable.

Comment: I know but how can i use `mousewheel` for multiple `Owl` !~

Comment: i Got Solution. thanks for comment.

Answer (score 0):

Basically we are using Multiple Owl With different Owl Reference with CSS `ID` so we need on `MouseWheel` moved with `Current` Method.

```
owl.on('mousewheel', '.owl-stage', function (e) {
    var current = $(this); // Just Put for on which you MouseWheel used
    if (e.deltaY>0) {
        currenttrigger('prev.owl');
    } else {
        current.trigger('next.owl');
    }
    e.preventDefault();
});
```